# need to return data from db transaction react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

i beginner in react native in main component i call database to execute my command and then i need to return data for me but after run console log me undefined can help me to solve this problem.thanks

my main component:

```
const requestJob = async () => {
let queryselect = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_messages ';
var Result = await Select(queryselect);

if (Result == false) {
    console.log('no data')
} else {
    console.log(Result);
}
}
```

in my database component

```
    var db = openDatabase({ name: 'message.db', createFromLocation: 1 });

db.transaction(tx => {
    tx.executeSql(
        query,
        [],
        (tx, results) => {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            if (len == 0) {
                console.log('no ');
                return false;
            } else {
                var temp = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i) {
                    temp.push(results.rows.item(i));
                }
                return temp;
            }
        }
    );
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use Promise

```
export const get = () => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql(
            query,
            [],
            (tx, results) => {
                var len = results.rows.length;
                if (len == 0) {
                    console.log('no ');
                    return false;
                } else {
                    var temp = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i) {
                        temp.push(results.rows.item(i));
                    }
                    return temp;
                }
            }
        );
    });
});
```

};

and read:

```
const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  const Read = async () => {
    const results = await get();
    console.log(results)
    setResult(results);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    read();
  }, []);
```